# java.net.Proxy using HTTPS scheme

Tags: java, http, networking, https, proxy

`java.net.Proxy.Type` is limited to `DIRECT`, `HTTP`, `SOCKS` only.
How to connect with a host using `HTTPS` proxy?

Curl equivalent example:
`curl --proxy https://PROXY_HOST:2272 -Iv http://example.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.net.Proxy` does not support HTTPS proxy.
Solution is to use other client, e.g. `apache.http.client.HttpClient`.